# connection drops, longer boot time, can't reach BIOS

Tags: boot, 17.04

I upgraded my Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.04 and since than i was having some problems in my system and one of them being consistently dropping my wifi connections.Recently i connected a corrupted hard disk to my pc and after that it is working weird. Boot time will go up to 2 minutes. I have Ubuntu 17.04 installed on my system. And maybe Ubuntu version is the problem.
here is the **Dmesg** output-->>

```
Call Trace:
[  934.359101]  dump_stack+0x63/0x81
[  934.359103]  __warn+0xcb/0xf0
[  934.359105]  warn_slowpath_null+0x1d/0x20
[  934.359120]  cfg80211_roamed+0x8a/0xa0 [cfg80211]
[  934.359166]  wl_notify_roaming_status+0xc5/0x140 [wl]
[  934.359204]  wl_event_handler+0x7c/0x200 [wl]
[  934.359207]  kthread+0x109/0x140
[  934.359243]  ? wl_notify_scan_status+0x330/0x330 [wl]
[  934.359245]  ? kthread_create_on_node+0x60/0x60
[  934.359248]  ret_from_fork+0x2c/0x40
[  934.359250] ---[ end trace 68752d54efd80339 ]---
```

What to do?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04LTS is supported until 2021, however 17.04 is already out of support (EOL was 13-Jan-2018) - so first I'd replace (or release-upgrade) your 17.04. Why did you connect a corrupted hdd?  To check its SMART status? or then to run `testdisk` to try and correct? Did you remove the suspect disk?  Either way I'd suggest moving to a supported Ubuntu release (for security reasons alone).

Comment: I figured that my wifi was the problem. so i blacklisted it in conf file and then everything worked well.
and yes upgrading is always the best option, i will do it. Thanks